# ash: ./MathWorksProductInstaller: not found, but file exists

Tags: matlab, alpine-linux, i3

I'm trying to install Matlab (R2022b) on Alpine Linux + i3wm, but I can't run the installer.

When I run the `install.sh` into the matlab unzipped folder, I get the following error:

```
./install: exec: line 292: /root/Downloads/matlab_R2022b_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64/MathWorksProductInstaller: not found
```

So I moved into `/root/Downloads/matlab_R2022b_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64` to find this file, and it exists. I also tried to directly run `MathWorksProductInstaller` executable, but I get the error

```
ash: ./MathWorksProductInstaller: not found
```

The file is an ELF64 so it should be run correctly. Some ideas to solve?